# Code Is Cut Off on Right Side

Tags: bug, android-app

Not sure if this has been brought up yet, I didn't see a post on it. In the first screenshot below, you can see that some of the code gets cut off.  When I try to scroll horizontally to see what is cut off, it switches to the Answer section. The second screenshot is of me trying to slowly swipe in the code block to the left.

[image: Screenshot 1 - Code gets cut off]

[image: Screenshot 2 - Attempting to scroll right goes to Answer section]

Comment: It's not exactly *obvious*, but... Tap the code block to view it in its entirety.

Comment: Ok. Simple enough. I think I tried everything but that. Thank you.