# Long lines in code sections are unviewable in stack android app

Tags: support, bug, android-app

When there is a very long line of code in the code section , it does not scroll when you swipe to the left. it will scroll only a tiny amount each time (one character at a time)

For example:

```
this is a really long line of code that will not properly scroll to the left when viewed on a device that's not wide.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to touch the code block. Then it will pop up a window-ish-thingy that you can scroll in.

[image: screenshot]

Same for large images (like the above; try it).

Comment: they should make that clear with an icon

Comment: @Don [In the Android App, make code blocks indicate their new behaviour](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217971/in-the-android-app-make-code-blocks-indicate-their-new-behaviour)